# Android GPU math

Tags: android, math, gpu

I want to accelerate my program by doing my math calculations on the GPU.

Is it possible in android. How do I do that?

So far I found [Renderscript](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html) with working sample(come with the sdk. its name HelloCompute) but it only works on android 3+

And the documentation is not that good...

Any other solutions?

Comment: What have you tried? NDK, NEON instructions? Have you looked at Renderscript (although only the Nexus 10 has GPU enabled)?

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005352/how-to-use-opencl-on-android)

Comment: @MorrisonChang A good part of Renderscript is now deprecated.

Comment: @Babibu You might want to edit this post after you have looked up the word 'copulation' in a dictionary!

Comment: @RaghavSood - only the graphics part, the computation part is still supported and the OP wasn't asking about graphics but math.

Comment: @Babibu - What calculations are you trying to improve the performance on and what have you tried already.