# Portable gpgpu tools between desktop and mobile

Tags: c++, opengl, gpgpu

At first, I study opencl because many people say opencl is portable between different vendors, devices, could write intuitive algorithms when compare to opengl. The problem is, for now, most of the mobile devices do not support opencl yet but opengl es 2.0.Do I have a better choice than opengl if I want my codes could run on desktop and mobile?Google provide another tools call render script for android rather than support opencl, but I don't want to use some platform specific tools if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably have to wait for more devices to use GPUs like the latest Nvidia Tegra.Till then take a look a [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005352/how-to-use-opencl-on-android) post.

Comment: Thanks for the link.Looks like I have no choice but to wait.