# Tensorflow Lite GPU acceleration - does it work for all OS versions or only for 8.1?

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Does Tensorflow Lite GPU acceleration work for all Android APIs or only for 8.1 (and mb only for specific devices like Nexus with specific chip)?

Does framework require any settings to activate GPU acceleration (in Java/Kotlin) or does it automatically choose between CPU/GPU and just CPU

There some official tensorflow examples and I see that minimal version for lite example is 15 API

Answer (score 1):

As I found at the moment gpu is used only on android 8.1, when the use_nnapi flag is set in the tflite interpreter

Comment: well, seems it's not just about Android OS, I tested on two different Xiaomi phones with 8.1 Android and it failed to run when I set `nnapi` as true

Comment: May be problem is in low version of SDK/NDK, when your build app