# How to enable hw OpenCL acceleration with Mali GPU?

Tags: gpu, opencl, termux, mali

I have a OPPO Find X6, its SOC is dimensity 9200 which have a Mali-G715 Immortalis MP11 GPU.

I have try to run clpeak in termux, but it report error:

clGetPlatformIDs (-1001)

no platforms found

here is my step(on a fresh install termux):

```
cd ~/

pkg install git cmake -y

ln -sf /system/vendor/lib64/libOpenCL.so /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/libOpenCL.so

git clone https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-Headers

cd OpenCL-Headers

cmake -S . -B build -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$PREFIX

cmake --build build --target install

cd ~/

git clone https://github.com/krrishnarraj/clpeak.git

cd clpeak

cmake . -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++

make

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/system/vendor/lib64:/system/lib64 clpeak
```

clGetPlatformIDs (-1001)

no platforms found

```
ls -lh /system/vendor/lib64/libOpenCL.so
```

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 72K Oct 27 02:52 /system/vendor/lib64/libOpenCL.so

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with termux and if that causes any issues, but it's worth installing [OpenCL HW capability viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.saschawillems.openclcapsviewer) to see if the OpenCL library can be detected there. You can see it, so it _should_ be findable. Also worth checking that the program can find/load libGLES_mali driver?

Comment: Maybe having a look at the thread below can help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005352/how-to-use-opencl-on-android